# How to have input directed to a constant?

Tags: java, netbeans, constants, user-input

I am creating a program in netBeans that takes user input of an elemental symbol and uses the atomic mass of that element. I declared all the elements as constants with their atomic mass, but realized I do not know of a way of getting the user input to connect with them. I'd rather not make if statements over 100 times.

Comment: Have you heard about `HashTable`?

Comment: @PM77-1 is right, a dictionary of some kind will probably be simplest.  Another option would be to use Refection to essentially treat the constant symbols as strings of text, to which you can compare the user input.  Once the constant symbol is found, you can extract it's value.

Comment: An array could also do the trick, but you would have a few empty cases. However, it seems to be logical to access that information with the atomic number, and as atomic numbers are *almost* contiguous, the array is well-fitted

Comment: +1 for having stopped to think "wait, there's got to be a better way" - many aspiring programmers don't, and proceed to write the if statement with 100 branches.

Answer (score 1):

A `HashMap` is a way to map *keys* of any one type you choose to *values* of any one (possibly different) type you choose.

```
HashMap<String, Double> atomicMasses = new HashMap<String, Double>();
atomicMasses.put("H", 1.008);
atomicMasses.put("He", 4.002602);
// And so on...
String symbol = ...; // Acquire symbol string somehow
if (atomicMasses.containsKey(symbol)) {
    System.out.println(atomicMasses.get(symbol));
}
```

The first generic type is the key type; the second is the value type. `put()` creates a mapping; `containsKey()` checks whether a mapping for the given key is present (note that this is case sensitive, so looking for `"h"` won't work); and `get()` gets the value that is connected to the given key (also case sensitive).

Since `HashMap` implements the more generic interface `Map` and the interface contains all of the operations you normally need to do, it is customary to write the declaration as `Map<String, Double> atomicMasses = new HashMap<String, Double>();`.